# Passing multiple environment variables a process managed by a supervisor

Tags: environment-variables, supervisord

I need to proxy multiple environment variables from `/etc/environment` to a process managed by a `supervisor`.

The following configuration worked for me with `supervisor 3.0r1-1` but `supervisor 3.2.0-2` reports an error:

```
environment=FOO=$FOO,BAR=$BAR,BAZ=$BAZ
```

> Error: Unexpected end of key/value pairs in value...

Some answers suggest to quote the values but if I do so, the variables wouldn't be expanded to real values.

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=environment, have you tried putting them all on one line?

```
environment=A="1",B="2"
```

(that is, `=` is used for both `environment` itself and for the key-value pairs, separated by commas, with the values bounded with quotation marks)

Also, where does $FOO come from? http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment says 'No shell is executed by supervisord when it runs a subprocess' so its not clear how you expect $FOO to work.

Comment: `$FOO` is an environment variable.

Comment: From where though? Supervisord isn't passing that to a shell, so its not going to know how to handle it other than as a string.

Comment: `Subprocesses will inherit the environment of the shell used to start the supervisord program.` `$FOO` is an environment variable of the shell used to start the `supervisord` program.

Comment: I defined those variables in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: @Kolyunya so did it, why it's not reading these variables ?